# MobaXterm how to change path of installation, from appdata to another location

Tags: windows, appdata

is it possible to change the path of where MobaXterm installs its binaries? I want it to be somewhere else instead of %appdata% because the school machine I'm connecting from disallows you to run or access things from %appdata%.

Comment: I encounter same problem today